# Does Ansible expose its auto-discovered Python interpreter?

Tags: python, ansible

**tl;dr: Does Ansible have a variable containing the current Python interpreter?**

As part of my playbook, I am creating a Python script on the controller (to be run by another command), and I want that script to be run by the Python interpreter being used by Ansible. To do this I am trying to set the interpreter in the shebang of the script.

If I were to set the interpreter manually, I could use the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable (and I have had it working that way). If I don't set the interpreter manually, then Ansible will auto-discover an interpreter, but I can no longer use the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable because it is not set.

From looking through the documentation I have been unable to find any way to see which interpreter Ansible has auto-detected. Is there something I've missed?

(Ansible version 2.9.10, Python 3.6)

---

The complete situation:

I am running Ansible on AWX (open-source Ansible Tower), using a custom virtual environment as the runner. I use Hashicorp Vault as a secret management system, rather than keeping secrets in AWX. For access to Vault I use short-lived access tokens, which doesn't work well with AWX's built-in support for pulling secrets from Vault, so instead I do it manually (so that I can supply a Vault token at job launch time). That works well for me, generally.

In this particular case, I am running `ansible-vault` (yes, there are too many things called 'vault') on the controller to decrypt a secret. I am using the `--vault-password-file` argument to supply the decryption password via a script. Since the virtual env that I am using already has the `hvac` package installed, I wish to just use a brief Python script to pull the password from Hashicorp Vault. All works fine, except that I can't figure out how to set the shebang on this script to point at the virtual environment that Ansible is using.

If I can't get a useable answer to this, I suppose I can change to instead pull the password directly into Ansible and then use the `--ask-vault-pass` flag to pass the password that way. It just seems to me that the interpreter should really be exposed somewhere by Ansible, so I'm trying that first.

Comment: `ansible_playbook_python` is the path to python interpreter on the controller used by ansible.

Comment: Aaah, there it is. @Moon if you leave that as an answer, I can accept it

Comment: Sure, glad that the information helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) `ansible_playbook_python` variable holds the path to python interpreter being used by Ansible on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

With `gather_facts: yes` you should be able to get the active python using the `ansible_facts.python` variable.

Comment: This is giving the python version used on the target host. OP is looking for python version used on the controller. Note that these can be different even when targeting localhost.